# Python, match values of 2 columns by checking information from another 3 columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe with the following columns: [company, first_name, last_name, gender, age]

I am trying to write a program that takes company, gender, and age as its parameters, checks to see if all 3 exist in a single row of the dataframe, and then outputs the first_name and last_name values existing in the same row of the dataframe as a list.

```
def employee_matcher(company, age, gender):
    if df_employee.loc[(lambda df_employee: df_employee['company'] == company)] == True:
        if df_employee.loc[(lambda df_employee: df_employee['age'] == age)] == True: 
            if df_employee.loc[lambda df_employee: (df_employee['gender'] == gender)] == True: 
                first_name = df_employee.loc['first_name']
                last_name = df_employee.loc['last_name']
                return list(first_name, last_name)
```

For example, if a dataframe contained the information

`['verizon', 'James' 'Wall' 'Male' 31]`

Inputting
`employee_matcher('verizon', 31, 'Male')`

Would return

`(['James'], ['Wall'])`

I continue to receive errors regarding the truth value of the dataframe and do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but I can't really explain it in better terms, but you can get a row from pandas dataframe by boolean mask like this. You need to use bitwise operations (notice the `&`) otherwise pandas raises an error of ambiguous truth value

```
employee_data.loc[(employee_data.company == company) & (employee_data.gender == gender) & (employee_data.age == age)]
```

Here's a solution that I came up with

```
def employee_matcher(company, age, gender):

    data = employee_data.loc[(employee_data.company == company) & (employee_data.gender == gender) & (employee_data.age == age)]

    return [data.first_name.to_list(), data.last_name.to_list()]
```

Hope this helps